# oceanwp+woo mobile cart sidebar text

Tags: php, css

It's probably obvious question, but im loosing it right know..
How can i reach "Cart" text in Mobile cart sidepanel?
I want to change it. Maybe anyone can help me?
Site i need help with : [www.prospecs.lt](http://www.prospecs.lt)
This menu cart appears only in mobile version when u click on the cart
Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Please try to give as much information and context as possible, so that other people can help you without having to ask lots of questions to understand the problem.

Comment: Im not sure what is unclear. 

1. Change text of the "CART" field.
 1.1 this panel appears only in mobile, its called mobile mini cart (sidepanel or sidebar. )
2. I can't find the variable for that to change it
3. Im asking for help